# CentOS 7 KVM host with two bridges

Tags: centos, networking, virtual-machine, kvm

I currently have a CentOS 7 host with a single NIC and would like to be able to use this NIC for two different types of bridges.

The host (CentOS) machine currently is currently pulling DHCP from my Meraki MX where my "main" subnet is configured.

CentOS has a default ethernet inferface (em1) with an IP address of 192.168.128.x

I have created a separate subnet for my "isolated" VMs in my Meraki MX (10.100.0.x) and on my CentOS machine, created a virtual NIC em1.30 (ie. VLAN 30, the 10.100.0.x subnet) em1.30 is used by my bridged interface, br0 which I use to feed the VMs I want isolated from my "main" network.

Now however I would like to put up a couple of VMs that ARE accessible on my "main" network (192.168.128.x) however I cannot seem to simultaneously bridge em1.30 AND em1.

I have read briefly that I might need to consider going to a "routed" solution, but I'm not sure what that entails.

My working above configuration has been put together via /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ files.